# How can I skip NestJs auth guards for public posts?

Tags: authentication, jwt, nestjs, decorator

basically, I have an authentication system based on guards, with three tiers:

decorators combining different guards:

```
@Authenticate() (checks user tokens, issues new)
@AuthenticateUser() (all above + fetches user and sets user in req.user)
@AuthenticateUserTier(requiredTier) (all above + checks if user tier is above requiredTier)
```

requiredTier is the tier the user needs to access the endpoint, like for example they need to be a member of the "pro" tier or the "business" tier.

The problem now is that some endpoints may or may not be accessible based on the user tier.

for example the posts found on:

```
mydomain.com/posts/5555
mydomain.com/posts/1234
```

One of these may be listed in the database under the "pro" tier, so then only members of the "pro" tier should have access to it.
But the other may be listed with no tier, meaning it is a public post.

If I put the @AuthenticateUserTier() decorator on the endpoint, then firstly, I do not know what tier the post requires, and secondly, I do not know if the post is public. And if it is public, I should skip all the other guards coming after, because we do not care if the user is authenticated or if they are of any tier. So the logic flow should be:

[logic flo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSTcK.png)

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to conditionally apply guards... I would maybe look into creating another decorator, like PostAuthenticate() decorator. This could look something like this:

```
export function AuthenticateuserTierCaption() {
        // check if the post is public here.
        // problem I do not know how to get post id from url here...
        // if not public:
    return applyDecorators(
        SetMetadata('tier', tier),
        UseGuards(AuthenticateGuard, UserGuard, TierGuard)
    );
        // if public return nothing.
}
```

If this approach works I am literally a few lines of code away from solving it, would highly appreciate if anyone could guide me in the right direction on how I can get the post id in the decorator and if I can make a db call from there.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering, the solution was to refactor the authentication guard system. Instead of having different guards and combining them in different ways, I refactored to have one single AuthGuard, and multiple "strategies". So for example the AuthenticateUser decorator which was previously combining the AuthenticateGuard and the UserGuard is now refactored to:

```
AuthenticateUser decorator calls:
setMetadata("strategy", "authenticateUser")
useGuards(AuthGuard)
```

... inside AuthGuard there is a simple switch statement.

```
switch(strategy){
case "authenticateUser":
    const canActivate: boolean = await authenticateCheck() && await userCheck();
    return canActivate;
}
```

with different cases for different strategies. So the different guards previously have been refactored into "checks" that are kind of building blocks for different strategies. And the strategies are deployed in the new decorators.

This also means that you can do more complicated stuff than just "first guard that fails denies the route" guarding... In my example I had the PostCheck run first, and if that returned true (post is public), it will simply short circuit the rest of the canActivate statement because I am using an OR operator between it and the authenticateCheck.